# How to make a js object and save it to a page dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Have a game that creates a random game object each time it runs. I want to save a copy of this randomly generated game to a unique URL so that I can have more than one person play this same game generation by going to the URL that was generated.

**Problem:**
Cannot seem to get the js game object to be saved and sent over to a freshly created unique webpage

**Goal:** 
Code that will be able to take a freshly created js object and save it to a unique page.

***What I've tryed:***
I've tried to copy the dom element that the game gets populated into, and then save this to a variable, and then send this variable to php and create a new php page with the js game in it. This did not work.
also I've tried copying an echo of the dom element with the game in it to a new page, but I keep ending up with the entire page, including the javascript part of the page that creates a new game. This results in the generated pages recreating a new game everytime they are refreshed because they include the same create new game code this is at the top of this file because this entire page is getting duplicated when a new page is generated. To fix that I've tried to remove the createGame() js at the top of the generated pages so that they do not create a new game everytime they are refreshed. This did not work either because the code is not removing lines at a time and instead appears to be removing characters one by one, but does seem to have an effect.

Please help solve this. I'm a bit new to this but I'm definitely giving this a shot and have been working on this for hours. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
<script>
     function createGame(){
        if( !document.getElementById) { return; }



        if (game1 == null){
            var game1 = new Game('newgame1', document.getElementById('putgamehere') );
        }
    //  var game1;
        game1.ImagePack('mainset',[['set1', 'Back Set 1']], '.png',25,36,"Main set");
        game1.ImagePack('cardset/h96/',[['bluepattern','Blue pattern'],['blue','pink'],['x','Red X']],'.gif',71,96,'oyc');


        //


        game1.startGame();

        //return game1;
}
</script>

</html>
    <head>
        <title> </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>

        <!--game files-->
        <script src="cgame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="cs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <!--Add Page Header-->
        <?php require "header.php" ?>
        <?php //eader "creategame.php"?>
        <div >

            <!--<div id="putgamehere">

            </div>-->

            <div id="putgamehere1">

            </div>





            <?php

                //$content = ob_get_contents();
                //$content = <script>;
                //global $content;

                $content = '
                    echo "<div><div class="game" id="putgamehere">

                    </div>"
                    $jsgamecontent = document.getElementByClass("game");
                    ;
                ';

                echo $content;


                //echo '<div id="putgamehere">

                //</div>';
            ?>

            <script>

                //Create new game
                createGame();

                //var content = document.getElementById("putgamehere1");


            </script>

            <?php


                //make new page url
                $newpageurl = "page1534";

                //make new page page 
                $newpage = fopen($newpageurl . ".php", "x");

                //create start game code variable
                //$startgame = "<div id='putgamehere'></div>";
                //$startgame = "<div id='putgamehere'></div>";
                //$startgame = $startgame . "<script>game1.startGame();</script>";
                //$startgame = "<script>game1.startGame();</script>";

                //$content = $content . $startgame; 
                //add game to new page
                $newgame = fwrite($newpage, $content);


                //Remove create game code from top of new created page

                //lines to replace with space 
                //$char = 0;
                //$content = file_get_contents("page152.php");
        /*      while($char < 100){

                    $content = str_replace(0, '', $content);
                    file_put_contents("page151.php", $content);

                    $char+=1;
                }*/
            ?>      

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Generated Code Sample:**

```
            echo "<div><div id="putgamehere">

            </div>";
```

Comment: What needs to be in the JS object? In a situation like this, you could have certain arguments or criteria as query parameters in the URL and construct a JS object based on these parameters. Like `/game?imagePack=blue-pattern&difficulty=hard` for just an example.

Comment: @sundaycode Just the game that was generated. Every time the function runs it creates a random version of the game. I could think of the game like a Rubik cube. Its always a different solve/game every time the function runs. I'm trying to save the specific game or "solve" to a unique URL for replay by more than one person. Thought of that solutuon as well but I'm using exiting game code trying to work how its setup.